# Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a `JPA Entity` as

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "name", "market_version" }))
public class Market extends MutableEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "market_version", nullable = false)
    private Version marketVersion;

    public Market(final String name, final String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.marketVersion = new Version("1.0", VersionType.MAJOR, VersionStatus.ACTIVE);
    } ... snipped
```

Which contains a `Version` and `Version` class looks like

```
public class Version {
    private String name;
    private VersionType type;
    private VersionStatus status;
    private DateTime publishedOn;
    private DateTime retiredOn;
    private Version parentVersion;

    public Version(@Nonnull final String name, @Nonnull final VersionType type, @Nonnull final VersionStatus status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.status = status;
    }
}

enum VersionType {
    MAJOR,
    MINOR,
    BOTH
}

enum VersionStatus {
    ACTIVE,
    RETIRED
}
```

When I try to save the `market` entity in test,

```
    @Test
    public void testMarket() {
        final Market market = new Market("test", "test market");
        final MarketCrudService crudService = new MarketCrudService(jpaRule.getEntityManager());
        crudService.create(market);
    }
```

I see error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.myorg.project.versioning.entities.Version, at table: Market, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(market_version)]
```

What exactly is the issue here? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is a `Version` in terms of a database type?

Comment: `Version` is not a database type, its an Object, I want to associate it like any other class like `String` or `Integer`

Comment: Since `Version` is not a known entity, so it cannot be mapped in any other entity.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to make Version a full entity with it's own table like you did with Market or if you want to save it as a part of Market you should make it embeddable using the @Embeddable annotation.

If you make it embeddable then you will have to remove the @Column annotation from the marketVersion field in Market.